# using geoplugin in windows phone 7 silverlight application

Tags: xml, web-services, windows-phone-7.1, reverse-geocoding

I was trying to use a web service : http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/extras in a windows phone 7 app to get the details of a location based on latitude/longitude.
i first tried the web service with random values and got this xml file

```
<geoPlugin>
    <geoplugin_place>Redmond</geoplugin_place>
    <geoplugin_countryCode>US</geoplugin_countryCode>
    <geoplugin_region>Washington</geoplugin_region>
    <geoplugin_regionAbbreviated>WA</geoplugin_regionAbbreviated>
    <geoplugin_latitude>47.6739900</geoplugin_latitude>
    <geoplugin_longitude>-122.1215100</geoplugin_longitude>
    <geoplugin_distanceMiles>0.07</geoplugin_distanceMiles>
    <geoplugin_distanceKilometers>0.11</geoplugin_distanceKilometers>
</geoPlugin>
```

But when i tried it using the same in my app it returned an empty xml file.
Here's the code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher pos = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        pos.Start();
        var mypos = pos.Position;
        pos.Stop();
        double latitude = 47.674;
        double longitude = -122.12;
        if (!mypos.Location.IsUnknown)
        {
            latitude = mypos.Location.Latitude;
            longitude = mypos.Location.Longitude;
        }
        WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://www.geoplugin.net/extras", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
        Uri req = new Uri(string.Format("http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/location.gp?lat={0}&long={1}&format=xml", latitude, longitude));
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        downloader.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(downloader_OpenReadCompleted);
        downloader.OpenReadAsync(req);
    }
void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(e.Result);
            reader.ReadStartElement("geoplugin_place");
            textBox1.Text = reader.ReadContentAsString();

        }
    }
```

Its gives an exception :  Element 'geoplugin_place' was not found. Line 2, position 2.

Is there anything wrong in my code or with the service??
Or if there's any other service which i might use to get the same result do tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discarded the geoplugin api and used Bing maps api and it worked fine.